# preg_match: equal sign in pattern

Tags: php, jquery, regex, serialization

I have this query:

```
list[One]=1&list[Two]=2&list[Apple]=fruit
```

this is the regex I use to return the values in the brackets and after the equal sign

```
preg_match_all('/(?<query>list\[(?<pagename>.*?)\]\=(?<parent>.*?))/',$source,$array);
```

**returns:**

```
One=  
Two=  
Apple=
```

Values that come after the equal sign are missing. Where's my mistake?

By the way, this query is generated with jquery's serialize(). Is there a better method to parse the values?

Comment: Are you aware of [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)?

Comment: I love when someone writes a function on it own while there is already a php function :D Almost for everything there is a php function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I made in a comment, you may want to look in to [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

However, if you change the final `.*?` to something like `[^&]*` then you'll probbaly have better luck (assuming this is a GET query string (or some facsimile) as `&` will have to be escaped from the sequence with `%26`)

Comment: +1 Nice! `parse_str($query, $matches); return $matches['list'];` worked like a champ, producing the same result as my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`(?<parent>.*?)` matches an empty string, so the result ist 'correct'. Try `(?<parent>[^&]+)` instead:

```
preg_match_all('/(?<query>list\[(?<pagename>.*?)\]\=(?<parent>[^&]+))/',$source,$array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you use the non-greedy `?` for `<parent>`, it's not grabbing the values. Try the other answers or if you can count on the format `list[<name>]=<value>` then you can avoid using regex altogether.

```
$query = 'list[One]=1&list[Two]=2&list[Apple]=fruit';
$pieces = explode('&', $query);
$matches = array();
foreach ($pieces as $piece) {
    list($key, $value) = explode('=', $piece);
    $matches[substr($key, 5, -1)] = $value;
}
```